# C# - How to set value to default from table in combobox datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

How can you set default value for combobox provided you get the value from table in database. I am thinking comparing the value with column [2]/destinationColumn to see which value in the table should be selected as default. This is my code so far which is wrong. Suggestion or an example code will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance guys.

```
                string sqlLookupColumn = "SELECT LookUpColumnID, SOURCE_NAME FROM TB_LOOKUP_COLUMN ORDER BY SOURCE_NAME ASC";
                DataSet dsColumn = databaseManager.GetData(sqlLookupColumn);
                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvCboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                dgvCboColumn.Name = "DESTINATION_NAME";
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvCboColumn);

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboDestinationColumns = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(row.Cells[3]);
                    cboDestinationColumns.DataSource = dsColumn.Tables[0];
                    string destinationColumn = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    cboDestinationColumns.DisplayMember = "SOURCE_NAME"; 
                    cboDestinationColumns.ValueMember = "LookUpColumnID";
                    if (destinationColumn == cboDestinationColumns.DisplayMember)
                    {
                        cboDestinationColumns.Selected = true;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things that i can see wrong

1- Your loop on the GridView wont work, do the loop on the `Dataset` instead of the Gridview...

2- You are comparing destinationColumn with cboDestinationColumns.DisplayMember which = "SOURCE_NAME" and you want `If destinationColumn = "InvoiceNo"`

3- Add the to the combo items using for loop and `.add` method, and do your if statement their.

To add the items:

1st add this class

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Then loop on the Dataset

```
for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
{
    DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
    ComboboxItem tmp= new ComboboxItem();
    tmp.Text = dr["SOURCE_NAME"];
    tmp.Value = dr["LookUpColumnID"];

cb.Items.Add(tmp);
if(dr["InvoiceNo"].ToString() =="")//Your condition here to set selected
cb.SelectedIndex = i;
}
```

Comment: i am just trying to set the default value of combobox column based on the value of variable destinationColumn. If destinationColumn = "InvoiceNo" then the default value of combobox should be "InvoiceNo". I hope that should clear up my question

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. i am trying to do as you say but can you give me an idea on how can you add value from dataset to combobox?